# Where does mongodump saves data by default?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to backup a database which uses mongodb (Ubuntu LTS 18.04)

So I managed to run mongodump command without any errors but still I can't find the location of the backup database. I only used the mongodump command so it must save it in the default location. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it will save your dumped data into directory `dump` which will be created in the same directory you run the `mongodump` command.

You can also specify the out folder for the dump like so:

```
 mongodump -u"username" -p"xxxxxx" --db=dbname --out=mongodata/
```